# How can I get the window in which an object was defined?

Tags: javascript

I would like to check if an object is an instanceof a certain built-in class. The problem is that my checking code might not be in the window where the object is defined, so `x instanceof String` would return `false` even though `x` is a `String`. What I need is something like `x instanceof getWindowOf(x)['String']`? But is it possible to define a function such as `getWindowOf`?

Or, we could solve this in another way if we were able to get all the windows of a JS application. `top`, and looping recursively through `top.frames` come close, but we would be missing pop-ups.

So what's a solution?

Note that I am just using `String` as an example. I really want to check classes like `Element` or any other classes defined in the browser.

Comment: What is the *certain built-in class* you want to check ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the cross-frame issues that you are having with the `instanceof` operator, and as you want to check a certain built-in object, I would recommend you to use the `Object.prototype.toString` method, it returns a string containing the internal `[[Class]]` property, e.g. assuming that `str`  is a String  and `arr` is an Array object both from other frame:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(str); // returns "[object String]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(arr); // returns "[object Array]"
// while
str instanceof String; // is false
arr instanceof Array; // is false
// and 
typeof arr; // "object"
```

More info:

- [`instanceof` considered harmful](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/)

Comment: But then, you wouldn't be able to check hierarchies. Say a HTMLDivElement is an Element.